# When setting a property, JPA executes an INSERT-Statement

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have this two entities

```
@Entity    
public class Athlete implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer athleteId;      
    private String firstName;       
    private String lastName;
    private Long phoneNumber;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="athlete")
    private Closet closet;
```

and also this one:

```
@Entity

public class Closet implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;        
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer closetId;

    private boolean isOccupied=false;

    private boolean isBroken=false;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Rank closetRank=Rank.REGULAR;

    @OneToOne (cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REMOVE})

    @JoinColumn(name="athleteId")
    private Athlete athlete;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date reservationStarted;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date reservationEnded;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;
```

I am not putting all the setters and getters method, which are in my code quite common.

In a Bean class I coded this methode:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ClosetService implements ClosetServiceLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="SportClosets")
    EntityManager entityManager;


    public Closet addAthleteToCloset(Athlete singleAthlete, String closetId) {
        //Find Closet
        CriteriaBuilder builder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Closet> queryCloset=
        builder.createQuery(Closet.class);

        Root<Closet> rootPassenger=queryCloset.from(Closet.class);

        queryCloset.select(rootPassenger).
        where(builder.equal(rootPassenger.get("closetId").
        as(Integer.class),closetId));

        Closet singleCloset=
        entityManager.createQuery(queryCloset).getSingleResult();

        singleCloset.setAthlete(singleAthlete);

        return singleCloset;
    }
```

So here is the problem.

When I go ahead and just create the Object singleAthlete, then persist it and then setting it as a property into the object singleCloset I get an exception:

```
 Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.DerbySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Die Anweisung wurde abgebrochen, weil sie in einer für 'ATHLETE' definierten Vorgabe für einen eindeutigen oder Primärschlüssel-Constraint bzw. für einen von 'SQL190317091523970' identifizierten und eindeutigen Index zu einem duplizierten Schlüsselwert geführt hätte.
Error Code: 20000
Call: INSERT INTO ATHLETE (ATHLETEID, FIRSTNAME, GENDER, LASTNAME, PHONENUMBER) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [5 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.models.Athlete@24790911)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:967)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:637)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2093)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:911)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:810)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2979)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1892)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1874)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1824)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4384)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1491)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1581)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3256)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:158)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.DerbySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Die Anweisung wurde abgebrochen, weil sie in einer für 'ATHLETE' definierten Vorgabe für einen eindeutigen oder Primärschlüssel-Constraint bzw. für einen von 'SQL190317091523970' identifizierten und eindeutigen Index zu einem duplizierten Schlüsselwert geführt hätte.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:895)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: ERROR 23505: Die Anweisung wurde abgebrochen, weil sie in einer für 'ATHLETE' definierten Vorgabe für einen eindeutigen oder Primärschlüssel-Constraint bzw. für einen von 'SQL190317091523970' identifizierten und eindeutigen Index zu einem duplizierten Schlüsselwert geführt hätte.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.completeExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseEXCSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetPreparedStatement.readExecute_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateX(Unknown Source)
    ... 78 more
]]
```

(Sorry for the German part, apparently I use the German version of derby)

Here is how I do this:

```
package com.servlets;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.Beans.AthleteService;
import com.Beans.ClosetService;
import com.models.Athlete;
import com.models.Closet;
import com.models.Gender;
import com.sun.xml.ws.util.StringUtils;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ManageCloset
 */
@WebServlet("/ManageClosets")
public class ManageCloset extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB
    ClosetService closetService;

    @EJB
    AthleteService athleteService;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ManageCloset() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }    

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher view =request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/closetEntryPanel.jsp");

        String closetId="";
        String athleteID="";
        String firstName="";
        String lastName="";
        String phoneNumber="";
        Gender gender;

        Map<String, String[]> parameterMap=request.getParameterMap();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : parameterMap.entrySet()){
            if(entry.getKey().contains("ADD_CLOSET_")) {
                closetId=entry.getKey().split("_")[2];
            }
        }

        athleteID=request.getParameter("atheteID");
        Athlete singleAthlete=null;
        if("".equals(athleteID)) {          
            singleAthlete=new Athlete();

            String gdStr=request.getParameter("gender");
            gender=Gender.valueOf(gdStr);
            singleAthlete.setGender(gender);

            firstName=request.getParameter("firstName");
            singleAthlete.setFirstName(firstName);

            lastName=request.getParameter("lastName");
            singleAthlete.setLastName(lastName);

            phoneNumber=request.getParameter("phoneNumber");
            singleAthlete.setPhoneNumber(Long.parseLong(phoneNumber));

            // It just persists the Object with EntityManager like:
            // entityManager.persist(singleAthlete); 
            // return singleAthlete
            singleAthlete=athleteService.addAthlete(singleAthlete);
        }

        closetService.addAthleteToCloset(singleAthlete, closetId);
        view.forward(request, response);        
    }

}
```

On the other hand when I dont persist the Object singleAthlete and just set the property of the Object singleCloset JPA persists the Object singleAthlete automatically. In this case the code works just fine. The question:

Can anyone explain me why this happens?

Comment: Post the two snippets of code that behave differently, and the complete stack trace of the exception. Also, please, replace the five unreadable lines used to get the closet by `Closet singleCloset = entityManager.find(Closet.class, closetId)`. that's how you get an entity by ID.

Comment: I'll do it, but other the problem with INSERT it works. I get an Object of the Entiy Class Closet. Why should I replace it?

Comment: I have no idea of what you're asking, because I can't see your code.

Comment: What about know can you see the code?

Comment: I don' think this has anything to do with how you save the athlete. It's still unclear to me what you're doing in one case and what you're doing in the other case, since you posted only one piece of code. The error message complains about a unique constraint SQL190317091523970 being violated. You should check in your database what this constraint is.

Comment: As you can see above in the servlet ManageCloset I persist an Entity Athlete over a Bean and then I set it as the property private Athlete athlete into the Entity Closet. At that time I get the Exception that I putted above. When I don't persist the Entity Athlete, that means when I don't call the method singleAthlete=athleteService.addAthlete(singleAthlete); JPA doesn't complain. It just set the Property private Athlete athlete of the Entity Closet and at the same time it persist it. So my question can you explain that? Why JPA complains when I first persist the Entity Athlete ?

Comment: SOLUTION:  The answer ist quite straight forward: The problem was that the property Athlete in the Entity Closet is being cascaded through the Attribute CascadeType.PERSIST. So when I first persist an Entity Athlete and then adding it as Property into Closet is like persisting the Entity Athelte two times....